# Graph not showing Data

Tags: ionic-framework, pusher-js

using this tutorial [Pusher](https://pusher.com/tutorials/live-graph-ionic) for realtime voting app, based on ionic.
Once you click on **Submit Vote**, it woundn't show any thing.

ionic port : 8100,
server port : 4000

Its might cause because of different ports?

**Update**
Just realize its has been blocked by CORS policy.

**code**

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
```

[image]

Comment: Please add some more details, like sharing some code or what you have tried so far etc.

Comment: @HasilT, I am using the same as based on tutorial. but once I click on submit vote, it not sow any data, I am wondering what I missed. I have doubt of port, even try 'Repo' and run as per instruction, but its not working

Comment: check whether the data is being received at the client side.

Comment: @HasilT, I missed the console error. check the update in my question